# How to hide commpletely comments in a wordpress page

Tags: wordpress

i have closed comments in a page still the below lines are displayed in the page .How can i disable these lines . someone please help me !

**Posted on October 12, 2010 by sankar
Comments Off | Edit
Comments are closed.**

Comment: Possibly a case for superuser.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of WP are you using?

In WP 3+ (and maybe earlier) you just go to the Dashboard, click Pages, click Edit for the page in question, scroll down to the section labeled Discussion, and deselect the Allow comments & Allow trackbacks & pingbacks boxes. Then trash any comments attached to the Page.

If you actually meant *Post* rather than *Page*, then Paul is correct in that a minor edit to the theme will be necessary. NOTE: whenever possible, do this with a *Child Theme* so you don't accidentally hammer the main theme.

Assuming you are using WP 3 and the default Twenty Ten theme, edit wp-content/themes/twentyten/comments.php (or create a child theme, copy comments.php, and then continue).

comments.php, line 70, reads:

```
if ( ! comments_open() ) :
```

Change it to read:

```
if ( 0 && ! comments_open() ) :
```

That effectively kills the line after it which is where "Comments are closed" is output, but without just deleting it completely. Obviously, if you are using a different theme you'll have to hunt down the appropriate line in comments.php for yourself.

Note that this is a quick-and-dirty hack which will affect all posts. You'll have to do something a little more involved if you only want to do this for selected posts.

Answer (score 3):

Add this code to your function.php file

```
// Disable support for comments and trackbacks in post types
 function df_disable_comments_post_types_support() {
$post_types = get_post_types();
foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
    if (post_type_supports($post_type, 'comments')) {
        remove_post_type_support($post_type, 'comments');
        remove_post_type_support($post_type, 'trackbacks');
    }
}
}

 add_action('admin_init', 'df_disable_comments_post_types_support');

  // Close comments on the front-end
 function df_disable_comments_status() {
return false;
}

add_filter('comments_open', 'df_disable_comments_status', 20, 2);
add_filter('pings_open', 'df_disable_comments_status', 20, 2);

// Hide existing comments
function df_disable_comments_hide_existing_comments($comments) {
$comments = array();
return $comments;
}

 add_filter('comments_array', 'df_disable_comments_hide_existing_comments', 10, 2);

 // Remove comments page in menu
 function df_disable_comments_admin_menu() {
remove_menu_page('edit-comments.php');
}

   add_action('admin_menu', 'df_disable_comments_admin_menu');

 // Redirect any user trying to access comments page
  function df_disable_comments_admin_menu_redirect() {
 global $pagenow;
if ($pagenow === 'edit-comments.php') {
    wp_redirect(admin_url());
    exit;
}
 }

  add_action('admin_init', 'df_disable_comments_admin_menu_redirect');

  // Remove comments metabox from dashboard
   function df_disable_comments_dashboard() {
remove_meta_box('dashboard_recent_comments', 'dashboard', 'normal');
}

  add_action('admin_init', 'df_disable_comments_dashboard');

  // Remove comments links from admin bar
 function df_disable_comments_admin_bar() {
if (is_admin_bar_showing()) {
    remove_action('admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_comments_menu', 60);
}
 }

 add_action('init', 'df_disable_comments_admin_bar');
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Wordpress pages - Click "Quick edit", you will see the option to give tick mark for comments, you can avoid that tick mark.

yourdomainname.com /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page

Then

Click quick edit of each page.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to edit the line that displays that out of your template.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to find out the following line in theme/page.php and delete or comment it.

```
<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can edit page template. Seaching `get_template_part('comments')` and remove it